# Getting A transport-level error when executing OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, openrowset

I'm trying to get data from a CSV file using OPENROWSET but I am encountering error:
"Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)"

I used the query below

```
select *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Text;Database=C:\Users\Public;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited(;)', 
    'SELECT * FROM [file.csv]'
)
```

I was able to get the query once when I used SELECT * but when I ran the query with the column names it caused the error above and now the query does not work even with SELECT * anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Open SSMS
Expand Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers
Double click the provider (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0)
UNTICK the "Allow inprocess" option

Comment: Why should this be tried? Do you think it is the solution? Then phrase that more assertively please and explain how it works and why it is supposed to solve the problem. If you mean it as an experiment and need the result to be able to create an actual answer, then please wait for your commenting privilege. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: there is no linked servers its opening empty in my case

Comment: The answer solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this come up today. I recently upgraded to 64-bit Excel on my system and noticed the `OPENROWSET` functionality broke. I [downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) and re-installed the engine and it seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this config for sql server

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1; 
RECONFIGURE; 

GO 
SP_CONFIGURE 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1; 
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
EXEC master.[sys].[sp_MSset_oledb_prop] N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DisallowAdHocAccess', 1
EXEC master.[sys].[sp_MSset_oledb_prop] N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
```